# Are questions about selling/marketing puzzles on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I just read [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/426/if-i-want-to-create-word-search-puzzles-what-approach-is-best):

> If I want to create word search puzzles what approach is best?
>
> It seems like most word search puzzles have a quantity of words that match some theme, arranged haphazardly, with some random letters filling in the extra spaces.
>
> If I want to create and sell word search puzzles what do I need to consider in my puzzle creation?

The question seems like a good one, and on-topic, until you get to the part about *selling* the puzzles. I don't think that's within our scope, though I do think the question would be good if that part were edited out. What does the community think?

Answer (score 1):

I think the fact that one is selling the puzzles one creates is not enough to make the question off-topic. In this case in particular, the fact is highly irrelevant to the question, so I have edited that part out.

Comment: I agree it's not enough to make the question OT; editing that part out was what I was going for as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would also be inclined to say that a specific question of 'What markets (e.g., Dell-style magazines) are available for this puzzle I've created?', where the answer is necessarily specific to puzzling and involves some aspects of the 'puzzle world', would be on-topic; essentially (and to borrow a criterion from other SE sites), questions where the users of this site are more likely to give a good answer than other sites.